# Are questions about locating a question on-topic on meta sites?

Tags: discussion, search, per-site-meta

I read a question years ago that *really* helped me in my programming career. I've been searching for hours today and can't find that original question. Would it be appropriate for me to ask on the relevant meta site a simple "Can you locate this quesiton for me" question? How much information do I need to provide?

Comment: I'd say go for it :-). Asking in chat may also be an option. As to: "How much information do I need to provide ?" - As much as possible.

Comment: @JonasCz That question should perhaps be rephrased as "How little is too little information to post such a question". If I simply say "Where's that one question where they said recursion is good", that wouldn't be a very good question.

Comment: Often, the best way to find a question is to start writing your own question, then let the recommendation engine to show you other questions that might be a duplicate of the one you are writing.

Comment: @200_success I tried that. The problem here seems to be the flood of similar questions which aren't the right question, hence a needle in a haystack problem.

Comment: In that case, we can't read your mind, so you might be better off asking in chat.